# Accessing class variables from methods located in separate files in Python

Tags: python

I have a class with larger methods (i.e. lots of lines of code) located in separated files as such:

```
├── myclass
│   ├── largemethod1.py
│   ├── largemethod2.py
│   ├── __init__.py
```

`__init__.py`:

```
class MyClass:
    classvar = "I am the class variable."

    from .largemethod1 import largemethod1
    from .largemethod2 import largemethod2

    def smallmethod(self):
        print("I am the small method")
```

`largemethod1.py`:

```
def largemethod1(self):
   # Lots of lines of code
   print("I am largemethod1")
```

`largemethod2.py`:

```
def largemethod2(self):
   # Lots of lines of code
   print("I am largemethod2")
```

Now I want to access the `classvar` from within `largemethod1` and `largemethod2`.  I have tried to do this with:

`largemethod1.py`:

```
def largemethod1(self):
   # Lots of lines of code
   print("I am largemethod1")
   print(MyClass.classvar)
```

But I get an `NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined` error.

What is the correct way to access the class variable from `largmethod1` and `largemethod2`?

Comment: All you're doing is importing some functions, you're not actually assigning the methods to the class. Also, I presume you mean 'self.classvar', not 'MyClass.classvar' in the last code block.

Comment: I mean `MyClass.classvar` which I understand to be the correct way to access class variables (as opposed to instance variables which would be accessed as `self.instancevar`, and defined in the `def __init__(self):` statement within the class).

Comment: But MyClass.classvar doesn't exist in the scope of largemethod1, and yet you've passed self as an argument. You're right that this is the correct way to access class variables WHEN you've instantiated the class, but you haven't and largemethod1 has no way of knowing what MyClass is.

Comment: OK.  So what is the correct way to add `MyClass` to the scope of `largemethod1`?  I don't think it makes sense to define `classvar` as an instance variable in this case since it should be assigned the same value for all instances of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough reputation for commenting. So:

```
def largemethod2(self):
   # Lots of lines of code
   print("I am largemethod2")
   print(self.classvar)


# No need for class instantiation because cls is our class.
@classmethod
def clargemethod2(cls):
   # Lots of lines of code
   print("I am clargemethod2")
   print(cls.classvar)
```